# Ubuntu samba shared folder is accessible from outside despite defined interfaces

Tags: ubuntu, samba

My problem is that my samba shared folder is still accessible from outside local network despite I defined interfaces and bind interfaces only. I would like to secure the shared folder to be accessible only in my local network. After configuration changes I restart service `sudo service smbd restart`. I will be grateful for any help.

Few line of my settings (smb.conf):

```
[global]
interfaces = 192.168.254.0/24
bind interfaces only = yes

[...]

[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
server string = Samba Server %v
netbios name = myname
security = user

[shared]
Comment = Samba Shared Directory
path = /home/myuser/shared
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
force user = nobody
create mask = 0775
directory mask = 0775
force create mode = 0775
force directory mode = 0775
```

Comment: We need more information here. Are there more interfaces on the machine? Is the machine configured to route packets? Explain more about what you mean by outside your local network.

Comment: Outside my local network I mean that I can view share folder using global IP address. What is "machine configured to route packets"?

Comment: Please [edit](https://serverfault.com/posts/1050537/edit) the question to explain your network layout and how you are testing this. If the machine has multiple interfaces is it configured to route traffic between the interfaces?

Comment: I do not understand. I guess I have one network interface - one ethernet cable connected to the machine (from main router). The main router redirect connections to server machine. I test it this way: my pc is connected to mobile network (other than server machine). I connect through ssh to the server machine, do changes to samba, then save and restart service. Then try to open folder using global ip (in windows explorer address type: \\IP_ADDRESS) - and it works, but it should not. Thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have set you Linux machine to the be the DMZ machine on your LAN. That means that ALL traffic sent to your router's IP address will be forwarded to that machine.

This means that all traffic on port 139 will be forwarded to you Linux box and because it's coming from the router it will arrive at the Linux machine on the interface bound to 192.168.254.0/24.

You can add `hosts allow 192.168.254.0/24` to your global section

And if you really want to be sure to prevent this sort of access you can add a iptables rule, something like:

```
iptables -A INPUT ! -s 192.168.254.0/24 --dport 139 -J DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are forwarding all traffic from your external router ip to your Linux host which should be protected by firewall policies.

Check if your router has the possibility to only forward required traffic from external (ssh) and deny everything else.

If the router can't do the job try with iptables on the Linux host.
The iptables commands below deny all incoming traffic by default and only allow ssh from anyone and cifs only from your local network. At the end log all traffic that will be dropped for troubleshooting.

Review and only implement them first when you have local access to make sure you are not locking yourself out.

```
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT ! -i lo -s 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.254.0/24 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT ! -s 192.168.254.0/24 -j LOG --log-level 4 --log-prefix "traffic dropped: "
```